# Trading Google Oauth2 Code for Oauth2 Token in Asp .Net

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, token, google-oauth

I have checked stackoverflow and tried several solutions but I continue to get a 400 when trying to make a post request to the google token servers to trade the code for an oauth2 token. The code is properly retrieving from the query string. I have tried URL encoding the secret, the redirect URL and changing the encoding on the request to ASCII. I know that google is finicky with the headers but the json response is intentionally vague and only returns "error: Bad Request" I cannot debug what is wrong with the request. I Also attempted to test the post request in the chrome REST client and receive the same error. I assume there is either an error in the headers or some other formatting issue but google does not return a helpful error code.

//Edited with working code

```
    //trade code for token
    public static String CodeTrade(String code)
    {
        String apiResponse;

            string codeClient = "code=" + code + "&client_id=xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&";
            string secretUri = "client_secret=zzz&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=" + "https://web.locusvisual.com/gadgets/smallview/loginTrue.aspx";
            string postData = codeClient + secretUri;
            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");

            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

                // Get the request stream.
                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

                // Write the data to the request stream.
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

                // Close the Stream object.
                dataStream.Close();

                // Get the response.
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

                // Display the status.
                apiResponse = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription.ToString();
                //Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

                // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

                // Read the content.
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // Display the content.
                Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
                // Console.ReadKey();
                // Clean up the streams.



                apiResponse = responseFromServer;
                reader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                response.Close();

        return apiResponse;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like your urlencoding might be messed up.  You urlencode the locovisual.com URL but nothing else.  400 reliably means that there’s something syntactically messed up with your request.